# Python Invalid syntax in elif

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

The code below shows in invlid syntax in the first elif statement. I have checked and rechecked my code several times, but cant figure out how to solve the error.

```
fileHandle = open ( 'gra1.txt' )
count=0
count1=0
fileList = fileHandle.readlines()
for fileLine in fileList:
    line=fileLine.split()
    if line[0] == '0':
        print "graph G%d {\n", (count)
        count +=1
    elif line[0] == '1':
        print "} \n"
    elif line[0]=='':
        continue
    else:
        count1 += 1
        if count1==1: a=line[0]
        elif count1==2: relation=line[0]
        elif count1==3: b=line[0]
        else:
            print a, relation, b
            count1=0
fileHandle.close()
```

Comment: Look at the __indentation__.

Comment: See this http://www.secnetix.de/~olli/Python/block_indentation.hawk

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `elif` is not indented properly...it should be indented the same way `if` is indented. Seeing the `else` block, it seems that you have by mistake indented the first `if`. Remember that `elif/else` should be preceded by an `if` always.

**EDIT:** corresponding to the edited question details: Why is the second `else` there? It isn't preceded by an `if`. I feel you need to get your conditions organized properly before writing the code.

One way to correct the code is to change this to an `elif` block:

```
else:
    count1 += 1
    if count1==1: a=line[0]
    elif count1==2: relation=line[0]
    elif count1==3: b=line[0]
```

You might want your indentation in Python to get better. Consider reading up a bit on that :-)

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply. butit doesnt work still.. my original code had it indented..and also i am using python in windows. does it create any problem regarding syntax errors?

Comment: @user3187705 Then please make sure the code in the question EXACTLY matches your local code... Else people here can't help you...

Comment: yah thanks for pointing out my mistake...i had missed the indentation while typing the question...now it is corrected..

Comment: Indentation is fine but you are still wrong. Look at the edit in my answer. You probably want to indent the second elif so that it's inside the first.

Comment: guess what? now i am getting error in line nineteen else statement!

Answer (score 0):

```
if line[0] == '0':
    print "graph G%d {\n", (count)
    count +=1
elif line[0] == '1':
```

It seems that you accidentally missplaced your first elif. In that state it matches no if's so you get an error.